# Direction which trajectories tend to a node sigularity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 0 \\
0 &-1\end{pmatrix} $$
be a matrix and $\varphi(t,x)$ flow of the ODE
$$\dot{x}= Ax, $$
$$x(0) = x. $$

It is well known that if $x = (x_1,x_2)$ with $x_2 \neq 0$,
$$\frac{\varphi '(t,x)}{\|\varphi '(t,x)\|}\to (0,1)\ \text{or}\ (0,-1),\ \text{when }t\to \infty. $$

Now, consider a smooth function $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, such that $F(0) = 0$ and $\mathrm{d} F_0 = A.$

I would like to know if there  exists a open neighboorhood $U$ of $0$, such that if $\varphi_F(t,x)$ is the solution of the ODE
$$\dot{x} = F(x) $$
$$ x(0) = x\in U.$$
Then it is satysfied
$$\frac{\varphi_F '(t,x)}{\|\varphi_F '(t,x)\|}\to (0,1)\ \text{or}\ (0,-1),\ \text{when }t\to \infty, $$
for all $x\in U$ except for points that lies in the invariant stable manifold
related to the eigenvalue $-2$ (in other words $\forall\  x \in U\setminus W$, where $W$ is a 1-manifold.).

I tried to use Hartman-Grobman theorem,
but this theorem only gives us a homeomorphism which is not enough to achieve the result.

Can anyone help me?

---

**EDIT:** In the paper [Rodrigues, H.: Known results and open problems on $\mathcal{C}^1$ linearization in Banach spaces. São Paulo J. Math. Sci. 6, 375–384 (2012)](http://www.journals.usp.br/spjournal/article/view/74496/78111), on page $2$, the author claims the following theorem

[image]

which solves the problem. However, I could not find this Hartman's paper.

Comment: Found a paper "Smooth Linearization of Hyperbolic Fixed Points without Resonance Conditions" that deals with your problem. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82518141.pdf

Comment: @Radost I don't think so... However, seems like that the result that I am looking for can be found in the paper "Hartman, P., On local homeomorphisms of Euclidean spaces, Boletin de la Sociedad Matematica Mexicana, Volumen 5, Numero 2, 220-241 (1960)." however I cannot find this paper. Take a look at the first theorem of  http://www.journals.usp.br/spjournal/article/view/74496/78111

Comment: See Hirsch & Pugh & Shub [Invariant Manifolds](https://books.google.com/books/about/Invariant_Manifolds.html?id=Py98CwAAQBAJ), in particular Theorem (5.1) and Corollary (5.4).

Comment: @user539887 Thx for the reference, I will check it now!